# Iterating through const unsigned char * containing "Extended ASCII" characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, sqlite

In my sqlite database for an iPhone app, I encode/compress a long array of integers (up to 5 digits) into a string using the extended ASCII character set to get it down to 2 characters.  (In other words, I encode it using base150)

When getting it out of the database, sqlite3_column_text() returns the string as a "const unsigned char *".  I can print this string using printf correctly (it shows even the ASCII characters over 128 properly) but when I try to iterate through it and access each character of the string individually to convert back into my integers, characters with ASCII values over 128 fail, because they're multibyte and it's only getting one byte (I think).

Example:

I have this string called encodedString which contains:   svÖ)

```
unsigned char c = encodedString[0];
unsigned char d = encodedString[2];

printf("%c", c);  //outputs "s"
printf("%c", d);  //outputs "\303"
printf("%s", encodedString);  //outputs "svÖ)"
```

I've also tried wchar_t with the same results.  I have gotten it to work using NSStrings, but it's very slow, and I'm doing this many thousands of times (NSMakeRange is the culprit according to the profiler), so I want it to be as fast as possible, hence C.

What's the trick to getting a single multibyte/extended ASCII character out of a string?

Comment: Make an NSString out of it.  That is the easiest way to reconstruct it.  It shouldn't be that slow.  How are you constructing them?  ASCII is never multibyte though, as far as I know.  The character you indicated though, doesn't appear to be ASCII.  It looks the unicode combining tilde.

Comment: I'm attempting to use the extended ASCII set as shown [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

When I do a for loop from 0 to 255, and cast the int to char, my output matches that table (my weird character above is 153).  In other words, if I hard-code an unsigned char to that character, it holds and displays it properly.  It's just when it's put into a string, I basically can't get it back out again as it was.

I did use NSString, and using NSMakeRange to get the individual characters out was a bottleneck.  The performance just wasn't acceptable.

Comment: I don't understand what you would be using NSMakeRange for.  Why not just make the whole thing into an NSString at once using `[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:encoding:]` using `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` ?

Comment: P.S. If you are only using 2 characters, how are you using `unsigned char d = encodedString[2];` ?

Comment: The problem isn't in creating the string, it's in decoding it back into integers.  I have a string of 12 characters, for instance, and I have to convert each character to its ASCII number, and I'm using NSMakeRange to access the individual characters of the string.

My code above with encodedString[2] is just a sample to show which character is giving me problems.  The string I used in my sample represents two coordinates, X and Y, each made up of two characters.

Comment: Doesn't sqlite store strings as UTF8 anyway?  How are you saving them?

Comment: I've confirmed that the sequence you are reading **is** in fact UTF-8 and not Extended ASCII.  Look into where you are creating these strings.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Regardless of the type of encoding it is though, how can I get one of those non-ASCII characters out of the string and into an unsigned char?

Comment: You can't because they aren't the characters you are expecting and furthermore they are no longer single-byte.  You are expecting '153' (0x99), but what you will get instead is '195 150' (0xC3 0x96).  That's why I said you need to show how you are making this string value.  I question the validity of what you are doing.  Extended ASCII is far from being standard.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `TEXT` column, I would recommend using a `BLOB` column where the data contains an array of integers of whatever size you want to use (perhaps 16-bit unsigned).

You can use `sqlite_column_bytes()` to determine the size of the column, allowing for variable-length columns to be used.

This will avoid the complexity you are currently facing.